# React change Input elements based on state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to change the Inputs that I display based on `id` state variable that the user can select in a dropdown. It's odd, but after changing the `select` ID, the Inputs are rendered properly, but it is setting the previous Input value to the new Input.
Also, the submit is validating Input that does not exist.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button, Form, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

const App = () => {
  const [id, setID] = useState(1);
  const units = [
    { UnitID: 1, UnitName: "101" },
    { UnitID: 2, UnitName: "102" },
    { UnitID: 3, UnitName: "103" },
    { UnitID: 4, UnitName: "104" }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ID was updated");
  }, [id]);

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const handleChangeDeposit = (id) => {
    setValue("id", parseInt(id));
    setID(parseInt(id));
  };

  const resetFields = () => {
    setValue("transactionComment", "");
    setValue("unitID", 0);
  };

  const renderTest = () => {
    switch (parseInt(id)) {
      case id === 3 || id === 5:
        resetFields();
        return (
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <Label for="transactionComment" className="mr-sm-10">
              Comment
            </Label>
            <Controller
              name="transactionComment"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: true }}
              defaultValue={""}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Input {...field} type="text" id="transactionComment" />
              )}
            />
            {errors.transactionComment && (
              <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">
                required
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      case 11:
        resetFields();
        setValue("transactionComment", "Laundry Room");
        return (
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <Label for="transactionComment" className="mr-sm-10">
              Comment
            </Label>
            <Controller
              name="transactionComment"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={"Laundry Room"}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  type="text"
                  id="transactionComment"
                  readOnly
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
        );
      default:
        resetFields();
        return (
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <Label for="unitID" className="mr-sm-10">
              Unit
            </Label>
            <Controller
              name="unitID"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: true }}
              defaultValue={0}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Input {...field} type="select" id="unitID">
                  <option value="0">Select</option>
                  {units.map((obj) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={obj.UnitID} value={obj.UnitID}>
                        {obj.UnitName}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                </Input>
              )}
            />
            {errors.unitID && (
              <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">
                required
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        );
    }
  };

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    if ([3, 5].includes(id) && data.transactionComment === "") {
      alert("Transaction Comment is require");
      return;
    }
    if (![3, 5].includes(id) && parseInt(data.unitID) === 0) {
      alert("Unit is required.");
      return;
    }
    alert("Updated!");
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <Label for="id" className="mr-sm-10">
                Select
              </Label>
              <Controller
                name="id"
                control={control}
                rules={{ required: true }}
                defaultValue={1}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    type="select"
                    id="id"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChangeDeposit(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
                    <option value="11">Option 11</option>
                    <option value="15">Others</option>
                  </Input>
                )}
              />
              {errors.id && (
                <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">
                  required
                </span>
              )}
            </div>
            {renderTest()}
            <div className="col-sm-3">
              <Label for="memo" className="mr-sm-10">
                Memo
              </Label>
              <Controller
                name="memo"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    type="text"
                    name="memo"
                    placeholder="12345"
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-greider-z3xpd?file=/src/App.js:0-5426

Thanks

Comment: I tried using your codesandbox but all it seems to do it alert that a comment is required. Can you update your question to include a set of reproduction steps for whatever the issue is?

Comment: That's the issue. The comment should not be required when it's not rendered

Comment: Can you update your question to include a set of reproduction steps for whatever the issue is, and rephrase your title and description so that it is clearer the issue is with field/form validation and not whatever "React change Input elements based on state variable" means? I'll take a deeper look at your sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is in your `renderTest` function, you've a malformed switch case.

```
const renderTest = () => {
  switch (parseInt(id)) {
    case id === 3 || id === 5:
      ...

    case 11:
      ...

    default:
      ...
  }
};
```

`id === 3 || id === 5` resolves to a boolean but you are switching on `id` which is one of the values `0`, `3`, `5`, `11`, and `15`. Since none of the `id` values is true/false the default case is rendered.

When `submitForm` is invoked the "comment" validation is checked.

```
if ([3, 5].includes(id) && data.transactionComment === "") {
  alert("Transaction Comment is require");
  return;
}
```

## Solution

Fix the switch statement to use two distinct cases for id 3 and 5.

```
const renderTest = () => {
  switch (parseInt(id)) {
    case 3:
    case 5:
      ...

    case 11:
      ...

    default:
      ...
  }
};
```